# Where to put methods (in entity or repo)

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, oop, design-patterns

I have two EF generated classes.

```cs
public partial class admin
{
    public admin()
    {
        this.user = new HashSet<user>();
    }
    public int id { get; set; }//PK
    //Other properties omitted for brevity
    public virtual ICollection<user> user { get; set; }
}
```

And

```cs
public partial class user
{  
    public string username { get; set; }//PK
    public string passwd { get; set; }
    public int admin_id { get; set; }//FK
    //Other properties omitted for brevity
    public virtual admin admin { get; set; }
}
```

users belong to an admin by using FK admin_id. If admin_id and username are equal then the user is an admin. Example: users 'Messi', 'Neymar', 'Suarez' & '123' all have admin_id 123. So user '123' is an admin. (Maybe not the best approach but it is not relevant for the question.)

Since these two classes are EF auto-generated and can change in the future I have another partial user class with the same namespace but in a different folder(so the methods keep preserved):

```cs
public partial class user
{
    public bool isAdmin()
    {
        return admin_id.ToString().Equals(username);
    }
}
```

I also have this user repository:

```cs
public class EFUserRepo : IUserRepo
{
    private Entities context = new Entities();
    public IQueryable<user> Users { get { return context.user; } }
    public user getUserByPK(string username)
    { 
        return context.user.Find(username);
    }
    public user deleteUser(string username){ return null; }//Yet to implement
    public bool saveUser(user user){ return false; }//Yet to implement
}
```

And I want to make another method for obtaining the useradmin of a given user, like this:

```cs
public user getUserAdmin(string username){ }//Note the return type is user, not admin!
```

**My question is**, where do I put this method?
I can put it in the EFUserRepo like this:

```cs
public user getUserAdmin(string username)
{
    user user = getUserByPK(username);
    if (user == null) return null;
    return context.user.Find(user.admin_id);            
}

public user getUserAdmin(user user)//Not relevant for question, but might be insightful for others
{
    return getUserAdmin(user.username);
}
```

And in my controller call this:

```cs
user adminUser = repo.getUserAdmin(loggedOnUser.username);//or use repo.getUserAdmin(loggedOnUser) for same result.
```

Or I can put it in the partial user class like this:

```cs
public user getUserAdmin()
{
    return this.admin.user.Where(x => x.isAdmin()).FirstOrDefault();
    //Due to DB setup always returns 1 user.
}
```

And in my controller call this:

```cs
user adminUser = loggedOnUser.getUserAdmin();
```

**I absolutely** have no idea what's the best approach.
What if I also want to make a method like:

```cs
public admin getAdmin(string username){ }//Note the return type is admin here, not user
```

Then I can add this to my user repository:

```cs
public admin getAdmin(string username)
{
    user user = getUserByPK(username);
    if (user == null) return null;
    return user.admin;
    //return context.admin.Find(user.admin_id);//Also works, but is it best practise to access the admin collection from within the userrepo, think not
    //return new EFAdminRepo().getAdminByPK(user.admin_id)//Also works, but seams really ugly
}

public admin getAdmin(user user)//Again, not relevant for question, but might be insightful for others
{
    return getAdmin(user.username);
}
```

And in my controller call this:

```cs
admin admin = repo.getAdmin(loggedOnUser.username);//or use repo.getAdmin(loggedOnUser) for same result.
```

Or I can put it in the partial user class like this:

```cs
public admin getAdmin()
{
    return this.admin.user.Where(x => x.isAdmin()).First().admin;
}
```

And in my controller call this:

```cs
admin admin = loggedOnUser.getAdmin();
```

**Real question might be**, do I use

```cs
ObjectX obj = repo.methodForObtainingObjectX(entity.params);
```

or

```cs
ObjectX obj = entity.methodForObtainingObjectX();
```

Comment: You should keep those methods in repositories. It is always good to keep entities as model and keep is as simple as possible. You should never include business logic in entities unless there is no way except that one.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, is that a name as a Primary Key? Do yourself a favor: get rid of that abomination right now. As soon as you convince yourself it's OK, you'll get a situation where there are two Joe Smith, or Jane Doe will get married, and you'll want to modify her name field, and can't because it's a key. Just give yourself another `int` field to use as a key, it's only a few more bytes per record, and always the right thing.

So, don't let people tell you not to add any logic to your model classes other than fields in the database or navigation properties. Models represent simple things like `IsAdmin` all the time, without having to resort to a separate class. Just slap `[NotMapped]` on it, and you're good to go.

Regarding where to put such methods when the logic gets more complex, I ask myself this question: how likely is the method to generate another trip to the database (and take into account possible lazy loading)? If very likely, it should probably go in the repo; if you *desire* for it to *always* generate another query against the DB, *always* put it in the repo. And when in doubt, put it in the repo.

Now here's the bad news: none of this applies to your situation.

First, **you already have the equivalent of `getAdmin` method on `User`** ... that's exactly what `User.Admin` is, isn't it? Just use your relations you have already defined for this purpose.

Second, if an admin always has a user associated, *there's a relation missing from your model*: you need, e.g., `Admin.Self` of type `User` to represent this 1-to-1 relation, then just worry about getting an `Admin` (either by `AdminRepo.FindByKey()` or `User.Admin` from a previously fetched `User`) ... once you have an `Admin`, `Admin.Self` will always get you her related `User` properties.

Identify all of your properties and relations in your actual model before considering any abstractions like repos, so your repos can do the simple CRUD operations they're meant to do.

Comment: I have a `person` table with PK id(int). The `user` table has a person_id FK...but it is not showing in my "answer setup" ;) Using `[NotMapped]` is an good option, haven't thought off that...(has to be in a separate partial file, since the auto-generated files will be overwritten) - About your answer where to put such methods, I am looking for design rules. And yours makes much sense! Just use the EF generated classes as POCO and if no trip to the DB is required for a method, put it on the model itself and if a trip to the DB is required or maybe required, put it in a repo.

Comment: You're right about a relation missing from the model! It's a setup we choice, maybe not the best but it works for us...I understand what you're trying to explain! You're also right about the getAdmin method and user.Admin beeing the same! My question was about(no punch intended!) _what if_ the navigation property wasn't there because of whatever reason. Then I have to use **option 2**. Again, you're tip about where to put a method, in the repo(when db trip is required) and when in the model(when no db trip is required) is very helpfull!

Answer (score 1):

Depending on your explanation (and the fact you are using ORM such as Entity Framework) it's correct to keep any data retrieval/modification functionality from EF object. EF objects are called "models" because they ARE models and the only thing they are expected to do, is BE models and represent database structure as POCO classes.

Thus putting some logic inside them (not to mention that you have to modify *.tt files to make this logic durable and don't loose on every model update) is not a good idea. So as @Jenish already said, keep model structure as simple as possible.

On the other hand, your repo is expected to provide all the necessary methods for data access, so definitely you have to put this method in the repo.

**UPDATE 1**

So regarding your next question about where to place and how to get user admin. I think that if you use repository pattern, it's better to break it down via "subjects", thus you will have userrepo, adminrepo and so on. Than, depending on logical belonging, some methods will go to userrepo, some to adminrepo and so on.

But generally, first of all, you have to make decision, are you using DB models in front end, or you have separate view model classes for only view rendering purposes. If first is true, I personally don't see big deal, if you just return user's admin via navigation property. in any case, you are using DB model class object as container. Thus I think that returning it directly as navigation property of user class, or returning it via dedicated repository method, won't change anything dramatically.

On the other hand, if you will introduce view model classes and make some transition between view model <--> db model objects, than braking all scenario on dedicated repos, makes sense.

Anyways, I'm sure, that main principle that every developer must always remember, must be "Keep it simple". I personally don't add any layer of complexity, if I'm not 100% sure that I really do need it.

Comment: EF generates partial classes. I put these classes togehter with the edmx file in a folder named dbEntites. I have another folder named dbEntitiesMethods where I put own made partial classes using the same namespace. These classes containing the methods. So they don't get lost when a new model must be generated due to a change in db structure. However, keeping the generated models just for use as POCO classes makes sense and is a clear choice in design, which I find helpfull...

Comment: But where would the method isAdmin() go?(from my own made partial user class) To EFUserRepo I guess: public bool isAdmin(string username) and then in controller use bool isAdmin = repo.isAdmin(loggedOnUser.username)

Comment: Yes, you are correct about partial classes. But I believe that it's better to use partial classes for model expansion, rather than adding data access & modification logic inside. And about IsAdmin property, I think as far as your "IsAdmin logic" is independent from data access and only includes some basic logical check, it will be just fine to place it in your model (second part of your partial class) and it will be there and I'm sure won't violate any pattern or methodology.

Answer (score 0):

So in the repository it will be. **One more question** (or should I start a new topic for this?)

Given this method in the EFUserRepo

```
public admin getAdmin(string username)
{
    user user = getUserByPK(username);
    if (user == null) return null;
    return user.admin;
    //return context.admin.Find(user.admin_id);//Also works, but is it best practise to access the admin collection from within the userrepo, think not
    //return new EFAdminRepo().getAdminByPK(user.admin_id)//Also works, but seams really ugly
}
```

I can do this in the controller(or anywhere else)

**Option 1:**

```cs
admin admin = EFUserRepo().getAdmin(loggedOnUser.username);
```

I can use the statement "return user.admin;" in the EFUserRepo because admin is a navigation property of user, but what if the navigation property wasn't there because of whatever reason. Then I would have to use one of the statements commented out.

- "`return context.admin.Find(user.admin_id);`"
- "`return new EFAdminRepo().getAdminByPK(user.admin_id);`"

And I find these statements very ugly and it probably isn't best practice? (Note that these statements are inside a `user` repository!)
One solution would be to remove the getAdmin() method from EFUserRepo and make use of an EFAdminRepo, so I can do this in my controller:

**Option 2:**

```cs
user adminUser = EFUserRepo().getUserAdmin(loggedOnUser.username);
admin admin = EFAdminRepo().getAdminByPk(adminUser.admin_id);
```

I think option2 is the way to go right? Please comment..